# Iterate through list to map current element as Key, and front and back elements as Values?

Tags: python, list, graph, iteration

alist = ['A','B, 'C', 'D']

what this list represents is: A<->B<->C<->D

I want to map this like the following:

A: B

B: A, C

C: B, D

D: C

At first I did:

But this is obviously wrong because it skips two elements.

```
alist = ['A','B', 'C', 'D']
graph = {}
i = 2
while i < len(alist):
    current, front, back  = alist[i-1], alist[i-2], alist[i]
    if current not in graph: 
        graph[current] = [front, back]
    else: 
        graph[current].append(front)
        graph[current].append(back)
    i+=1
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Will the list only contain unique element, or is that why you are checking `if current not in graph`?

Comment: What happens when i is 0? Think through it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oops I guess it is unnecessary for this case since we are only looking at one list, but it originally takes a list of graphs! I simplified it but forgot to take that out

Comment: @Natecat if i=0, the front and back would be out of index.. ummm

Comment: @bisuke Well, not exactly, because of how python indexing works. They would be -1 and -2, which refers to the two last elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already there are many solutions, this one is very easy to understand:

```
alist = ['A','B', 'C', 'D']
graph = {}
for index, item in enumerate(alist):
    if index == 0:
        if len(alist) == 1:
            graph[item] = []
            break
        graph[item] = [alist[index+1]]
    elif index == len(alist)-1:
        graph[item] = [alist[index-1]]
    else:
        graph[item] = [alist[index-1], alist[index+1]]
```

Output:

```
>>> print graph

154: {'A': ['B'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'C': ['B', 'D'], 'D': ['C']}
```

Thanks @mglison for pointing  out the exception when `len(alist) == 1` , Edited

Comment: I like it.  It might be slightly nicer than mine for the hard-coded only-2-elements case.

Comment: Indeed this one's very logical and easy to understand. Thank you!

Comment: There is one edge case that this doesn't quite handle properly.  If `alist = ['A']`, then this will raise an `IndexError`.  I'm not sure what the behavior _should_ be ... But it _probably_ isn't an `IndexError` :-)...

Comment: Right you are ! Edited!

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
graph = {}
for i, item in enumerate(alist):
    connections = []
    for j in (i-1, i+1):  # look at element before and after the i'th
        if 0 <= j < len(alist):  # check if the index is valid for `alist`
            connections.append(alist[j])
    graph[item] = connections
```

Note that this only works for `alist` is a sequence of some sort.  It won't work for generators.  Also, I'm not usually a fan of checking if an index is in the list.  I'd rather `try: ... except IndexError: ...` (EAFP), but `IndexError` wouldn't be raised for negative `j` so I avoided that route for this particular application).

Comment: Very neat solution

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely not what you want, but it was such a cute one line solution to your problem I could not resist.

```
 > l = ['A','B','C','D']
 > { k: filter(None, [v1,v2]) for (k,v1,v2) in zip(l,[None]+l[:-1],l[1:]+[None]) }
 {'A': ['B'], 'C': ['B', 'D'], 'B': ['A', 'C'], 'D': ['C']}
```

Comment: I think that `[None] + l[:-1]` could be simplified (and optimized) to just `[None] + l` since `zip` truncates when the shortest iterable runs out.  It would cut out one intermediate list anyway ...

Comment: @mgilson good catch, although that sort of kills the symmetry of it. Not that any of this matters... this isn't [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution (there are better ways I'm sure for longer items).

```
graph = {alist[0]: alist[1], alist[-1]: alist[-2]} # terminal elements
for i in range(1, len(alist)-1):                   # middle elements
    graph[alist[i]] =  [alist[i-1], alist[i+1]]

In [43]: for k, v in sorted(graph.iteritems()): 
    print "{} -> {}".format(k, v) 
   ....:     
A -> B
B -> ['A', 'C']
C -> ['B', 'D']
D -> C
```